# Can't find the Kotlin REPL sidebar

Tags: kotlin

I'm a newbie and under a Kotlin REPL session. But **I couldn't find the sidebar** which shows the red circled exclamation marks or green triangles. Here are the pictures I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools --> Kotlin --> Kotlin REPL in your IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: Kotlin REPL Settings]